# Disconnect node-xmpp client

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmpp, node-xmpp

I am looking at [node-xmpp](https://github.com/astro/node-xmpp) and [node-simple-xmpp](https://github.com/arunoda/node-simple-xmpp) and I am trying to make a simple client.
Everything works fine, except the disconnect.

I have made the following file after the [example](https://github.com/arunoda/node-simple-xmpp/blob/master/examples/echo.js) of simple-xmpp:

```
var xmpp = require('simple-xmpp');

xmpp.on('online', function() {
    console.log('Yes, I\'m connected!');
    xmpp.send('test2@example.com', 'Hello test');
    // OK UNTIL HERE, DISCONNECT NOW
});

xmpp.connect({jid: 'test@example.com/webchat', password: 'test', reconnect: 'false'});
```

But I don't know how to disconnect. I tried to send a stanza with unavailable type:

```
stanza = new xmpp.Element('presence', {from: 'test@example.com', type: 'unavailable'});
xmpp.conn.send(stanza);
delete xmpp;
```

This is causing the client to go temporarily offline, but the problem is, it reconnects after a few seconds and keeps sending 'presence' stanza.

I have also tried calling xmpp.conn.end(), which also disconnects but it gives an error afterwards:

```
node_modules/simple-xmpp/node_modules/node-xmpp/lib/xmpp/connection.js:100
    if (!this.socket.writable) {
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'writable' of undefined
```

So, what am I doing wrong? I am sure there is an easy way to disconnect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, `<presence type='unavailable'/>` does not always actually disconnect you; in your server, it looks like it might be, but your client is auto-reconnecting.  `delete xmpp` is not actually causing your object to be cleaned up, it's just removing it from the local namespace.

In the second case `send()` isn't writing your stanza to the underlying socket immediately.  If you close the socket with `end()` right afterwards, the socket is closed when the write actually happens.

If you add a short timeout after you call `send()`, before calling `end()` it will work.  To make it *good*, you'll want your library developers to give you a callback when `send()` has actually written to the socket.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it worked even with a `setTimeout(function(){ xmpp.conn.end() }, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You should also check this out https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7395

In short if client is using  to open connection it should use  to kill that same connection.

To be more precise:

```
<close xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-framing" />
```

Solution of "Joe Hildebrand" also solved my problem, but this seemed more proper way for me.

Comment: please provide a full answer to the question, not just the link ad the link might be out of date.

Comment: Sorry, i did not put part of code in "code tags" so it was not visible so I actually provided full answer, but in non friendly way for browser :D Edited ;)